# I am getting this error all of a sudden in pycharm(python 3.9)....the program was working fine

Tags: tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users***\PycharmProjects\Comp. Project 2022\Menu Options\Main Menu.py", line 3, in

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Process finished with exit code 1

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaBMU.png)

Comment: Prolly has a file named `tkinter.py` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Many online sources are brief about it, I use `pycharm` for python.

I went to the source directory where i installed tkinter using `pip install tk` and searched `tkinter.py`.

I got multiple results `_tkinter.py`

I deleted them all. Then the program started working.

Comment: `pip install tk` doesn't install tkinter, it installs a very old package for TensorKit. You can't install tkinter with pip.